# Android correct place to intialize LocalBroadcastReceiver for an activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

I have an android activity that has BroadcastReceiver as below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.i("TAG", intent.getAction());
        }
};
```

The problem is I am receiving message from network and depending on message type I create the activity or send Broadcast message to activity, since I receive message very fast the message type to create activity arrives right before(in few milliseconds) the message type to send Broadcast message to the same activity and I get an error `handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy` researching a bit I found that the activity might not be created correctly before I send the broadcast intent.
So I made the thread sleep for 3 seconds.

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now everything works as expected but the above looks ugly and a bit hackish, is there a better way to send broadcast intent right before the activity creation?

Comment: Could you post the [stack trace](/a/23353174) of the exception?

Comment: I see the error that get logged in logcat without any exception or app crash, so i don't have any stacktrace

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code, but I suspect that the problem is what you're doing once you receive the message (that is, you're doing something that relies on something that's not available).

Comment: You are probably filtering your logcat which is why you don't see the stacktrace. Try to disable filtering and see if you see the full exception log.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the `Activity` and sending a broadcast `Intent` to it, just put the contents of the broadcast `Intent` in the `Intent` you use to start the `Activity` (as an "extra"). Then you don't need the 3 second delay, you just only send the broadcast `Intent` if the `Activity` is already running.

Comment: There are multiple paths to start the activity and some path might not have the Intent already present so removing broadcast Intent is not possible.

Comment: Then you'll need to find the whole stack trace in the logcat and post that so we can see where the code is crashing. I don't have enough info to help you any more than this.